# Trace 32 command to read the Breakpoint source file

Tags: debugging, trace32

Is there a command in Trace 32 to read the field marked in this screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrmkS.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean with "read the Breakpoint source file"? I think there is no thing as a "Breakpoint source file"...  From your screenshot I guess, you want to get the symbol (from the ELF), which related to your Program Counter. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, is there a command for that

Answer (score 0):

To get symbolic which equals to an arbitrary address (or precedes the address in case there is no symbol exactly for the address), use the PRACTICE function `sYmbol.NAME()`.

To get the address to where the program counter is pointing to, use the PRACTICE function `PP()`.

Putting both together you get an expression which prints the symbol related to the program counter:

```
ECHO sYmbol.NAME(PP())
```

To get a symbol representation which matches exactly the location of the program counter (in case there is no symbol *exactly* matching the location of the program counter) you can use the following:

```
PRIVATE &sym &offset
&sym=sYmbol.NAME(PP())
&offset=PP()-&sym
IF &offset!=0
    &sym="&sym+&offset"
ECHO "&sym"
```